# font families where after typing one character the cursor still remains on the character

Tags: html, fonts, font-face, font-size, webfonts

If you notice in this font family -http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/CAC-Champagne,
the 'T' almost overlaps with 1/4 of the 'U'. 
When I have included this font family using @font-face, and I type, the cursor types the T but remains on it only.
[image: The cursor on the web browser has changed to the arrow]

This causes the problem that when I copy this text into a span with its width as 'auto', the span does not show the complete 'T' but till the point where the arrow is .
Any solution for this?

Comment: Here the text cursor on the web browser has changed into an arrow upon taking a screenshot.
Somehow the extra 'T' which extends into the 'U' as visible on the webpage is not recognized, neither while typing text nor by a span to which the text is copied anagrammatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of the font, and it is not uncommon in script fonts. For example, the advance width of the letter “T” is considerably smaller (1,146 units, to be exact) than the width of the glyph, i.e. the width of its bounding box (which is 1,786 units). This is intentional, part of the design that makes the result resemble handwritten text.

For inline elements containing text in this font, use some right padding to compensate for the effect. Although the effect of extending to the right of the bounding box is mostly a feature of glyphs for uppercase letters, which normally do not appear at end of word, it also occurs for lowercase  letters such as “f”. A value of '0.25em' would seem to be suitable, based on the following simple experiment:

```
<span style="font-family: CAC Champagne; font-size: 32pt;
border: solid red 1px; padding-left: 0.25em;
padding-right: 0.25em;">f</span>
```

Comment: I ended my adding the leading and trailing spaces but this value of padding added is relative to the font size and the script used at that time. So isnt it a relative value?

Comment: @BhumiSinghal, I don’t understand your question. If you mean adding space characters, I don’t think you should do that. The width of a space depends on font size and font family. The width of the `em` unit depends on the font size only, but you can select the multiplier suitably.

Comment: Wat i meant was that the extension of the characters will depend on the script written and the em values rendering depends on the browsers and their version i guess. So doesnt it become a relative and hit and trial solution? Though i couldnt think of any better one.

Comment: OK, I see; yes, the padding values need to be decided on the basis of experimenting with the font (though I peeked at the glyph metrics with DTL OTMaster Light, and it seems that the letter “f” is the worst-case lowercase letter, and `0.25em` handles it).